# How do I fill a rectangle with the exception of a area

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to fill a rectangle in a winforms application less a ellipse in the center that allows the image in the background to show through.

can anyone give me a hint on which way to go on this,

thanks.

this is what I have come up with so far:

```
  path.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(30, 30, 100, 100));
  path.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(50, 50, 60, 60));
  gfx.FillPath(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), path);
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e){
    var rgn  = new Region(new Rectangle(50, 50, 200, 100));
    var path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddEllipse(60, 60, 180, 80);
    rgn.Exclude(path);
    e.Graphics.FillRegion(Brushes.Blue, rgn);
}
```

Comment: I like this method better that what I have come up with

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with what you came up with, as long as none of the excluded objects overlap (with each other or the containing rectangle).

Answer (score 1):

The easy way:

- Fill the Reacngle first
- Then Fill the Ellipse (with a Transparant brush)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear enough what kind of transparency is required there.  The simple way is to invert the problem.  Use a TextureBrush to draw the image with Graphics.FillEllipse().

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region.aspx).  Create a rectangle region, exclude an ellipse and then fill it.